# Returning a function in main

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, function

the purpose of the function it to take a number and flip it, means if the number is 1024 it will return 4201...

After creating the function I try to call it and check if it's actually working but when debugging it seems like it just skips the function and just print 1024.

What is my problem here?

On the top you can see the function and on the bottom there's the main() where I also call the function.

```
unsigned long reverse(unsigned int x)
{
    
    int current, newX = 0, i = 1;

    while (x != 0)
    {
        current = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
        newX = newX * 10 + current;
    }


    return newX;
}


int main()
{

    unsigned int x;

    printf("Enter number\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &x);


    reverse(x);

    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x = reverse(x);`

Comment: You do not assign the return value of `reverse` to any variable. And parameter `x` inside `revers` is only a copy of the provided argument that just by accident happens to have same name.

Comment: what language are you writing? C and C++ are two different languages. They have some similarities and your code could be either of the two, though thats only because you left out the includes, latest when you add them it is either C or C++, not both

Comment: And you should return `newX`

Comment: I missed it before: `scanf_s` is not standard C++, hence I assume this is C

Comment: Hey yeah it's C but since they are similar I thought maybe also c++ people could help me too. Anyway you were right @pVCaecidiosporeadduced thanks I didn't notice, you saved me , thanks :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's kind of not standard C either. It's part of the optional bounds-checking interface, which was a fiasco lib that no compiler implemented.

Comment: `c++ != c` , not even similar, dont mix them up

Comment: @Lundin thanks. Didnt know that. In that case my edit wasnt justified. Needs OPs clarification

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The OP clarified that it is C in a comment. However, we generally don't remove either tag once answers have been posted in one of the languages, because that turns those existing answers obsolete. Arguably, people who answer without clarifying the language first only have themselves to blame. Details can be found in tag usage below C or C++ tag wikis.

Comment: Don't add `(SOLVED)` behind the title of your question or anywhere in the text. And don't change the code in the question to be correct.  If an answer fully solved your problem accept that one, or write your own and accept it. Alternatively, if you think it is just like a typo, you could also think about deleting your question.

Comment: @Lundin didnt see that comment. And yes, agreed, wasnt my intention to invalidate existing answer. Not sure if it can be improved anymore. I already had my chance to mess it up and will just get a coffee.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour due to use of  `%d` format specifier for `scanf()`/`printf()` and related functions.    `%d` tells the functions to ASSUME the corresponding argument is an `int` (or `int *` when reading) and behaviour is undefined when an `unsigned` is passed.   Use `%u` instead.   Also, change the statement `reverse(x)` to `x = reverse(x)`.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, read the number as `std::string`, then use `std::reverse` on the string.

Answer (score 1):

Take a parameter by reference and assign newX to it. Extra: some refactor with using cin, cout

```
#include <iostream>

void reverse(unsigned int & x)
{
  int current, newX = 0, i = 1;
  while (x != 0)
    {
      current = x % 10;
      x = x / 10;
      newX = newX * 10 + current;
    }
  x = newX;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int x;
  std::cout << "Enter number\n";
  std::cin >> x;
  reverse(x);
  std::cout << x;

  return 0;
}
```

... or use return value and reassign to "x" in main:

```
unsigned int reverse(unsigned int x)
{
  int current, newX = 0, i = 1;
  while (x != 0)
    {
      current = x % 10;
      x = x / 10;
      newX = newX * 10 + current;
    }
  return newX;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int x;
  std::cout << "Enter number\n";
  std::cin >> x;
  x= reverse(x);
  std::cout << x;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try if that change would have the expected result?

Comment: @t.niese, thank you, I've fixed the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing the returned value of the function.
To get the desired results  do
x = reverse(x);

Comment: Did you check if that really gives the expected result?